# unable to save data before saving models in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, models

I am trying to build a single custom registration form for companies, admin, and staff. When I create my superuser, my 'Account type' is 'admin', but when I try to register as a a company my 'Account type' is empty.

I can set a default value in my model class, but I would like to add more different types of 'Account type' in the future.

I also don't want to have a dropdown for the field

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager,
    AbstractBaseUser
)

# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, account_type=None, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email address is required')

        user = self.model(
                email = self.normalize_email(email),
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                account_type = account_type
            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                account_type = 'staff',
                password = password
            )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                account_type = 'admin',
                password = password
            )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from accounts.forms import RegisterForm

# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.account_type = 'company'
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponse('account created')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm();
    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', context)
```

Comment: Based on which data do you want to decide whether the user will be admin, company or staff?

Comment: when companies tries to create their profile they first need to register using the custom all purpose registration form, so when they "post" the form i want to update the db in the views.py  the filed / data that i am considering is the  "account_type" field. 

you can view my attached views.py file.

all i want is to make sure that my register function in views.py file run successfully, my user.account_type = 'company' is not working

Comment: Which means I can register and tell "I'm admin" and the registration gives me proper permissions? Looks like a huge security issue to me.

Comment: got any other alternative.? btw, i am just using that field to make sure that whenever any company register, profile associated with the id is also created... nothing to do with main admin.